# When I install elementary OS, I always fail

Tags: system-installation

Every time I install it with USB, I always get stuck in the logo interface. What should I do? My computer is dual video card, I don't know if there is any impact

Answer (score 1):

Try the install without adding 'third-party' drivers during install process (checkbox). This should then cause the use of the basic Ubuntu video driver(s).

As a side note, I have installed this OS in all versions many times...sometimes the initial boot process takes a little longer than normal. It might be a simple case of delayed gratification solved by waiting a bit longer... I can't say why but perhaps someone with real OS knowledge can answer...HTH

Answer (score 0):

Hi there good to have you here.

I got a silly question for you, did you check the image hash before installing it on the USB stick?  If not, that might be the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a brilliant question!  Always check the checksum of the ISO after download. Please see https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation